# flutter How to hide widget from ui without taking any space

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I need to hide a widget in a row. I know it looks duplicated. I searched and tried many ways to hide this widget but it still have space. so this is what I used to solve it 
1- I used Visibility 
2- I used Offset 
3- I used If case 
but the widget still have place in my row , I need it to be removed and and don't take any space in my Ui. 
here is my code below in my . any help is very appreciated

```
class _AppState extends State<App> {
  bool _hasImage ;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    _hasImage = false ;
    return Material(
      child: Container(
        child: Container(
          child: Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
            children: <Widget>[
              Wrap(
                direction: Axis.vertical,
                alignment: WrapAlignment.start,
                children: <Widget>[
                  IconButton(
                    icon: Icon(Icons.camera_alt),
                    iconSize: 40.0,
                    color: Color.fromRGBO(88, 60, 26, 1),
                    onPressed: () {
                    },
                  ),
                  Text(
                   'Camera',
                    style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 17.0),
                  )
                ],
              ),
              Wrap(
                direction: Axis.vertical,
                alignment: WrapAlignment.start,
                children: <Widget>[
                  IconButton(
                    icon: Icon(Icons.image),
                    iconSize: 40.0,
                    color: Color.fromRGBO(88, 60, 26, 1),
                    onPressed: () {
                    },
                  ),
                  Text(
                    'Gallery',
                    style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 17.0),
                  )
                ],
              ),
              Visibility(
                visible:  _hasImage,
                maintainSize: false,
                child: Wrap(
                  direction: Axis.vertical,
                  alignment: WrapAlignment.start,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    IconButton(
                      icon: Icon(Icons.delete),
                      iconSize: 40.0,
                      color: Color.fromRGBO(88, 60, 26, 1),
                      onPressed: () {

                      },
                    ),
                    Text(
                      'Remove',
                      style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 17.0),
                    )
                  ],
                ),
              )
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: other useful widget for the same is - `Offstage` https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Offstage-class.html

Comment: @anmol.majhail You're right but there are couple of warning on using it in situations like this, first `Animations continue to run in offstage children, and therefore use battery and CPU time, regardless of whether the animations end up being visible.` and second  `To hide a widget from view while it is not needed, prefer removing the widget from the tree entirely rather than keeping it alive in an Offstage subtree.`

Comment: To cope up with Animation part, you further need to use `TickerMode`

Comment: @anmol.majhail even with offsetage it still have space in row

Comment: take out - `_hasImage = false ;` from build

Comment: @CopsOnRoad , I will keep and show this widget dependent on _hasImage value .

Comment: @anmol.majhail NO body noticed that, haha, that's the right solution

Comment: @anmol.majhail No dear, you are the one who should write it as answer, I'll delete mine. Please go ahead :)

Comment: @anmol.majhail , I know  i just put it as hard code but i check it in another condition :)

Comment: @CopsOnRoad, I appreciate that :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
bool _hasImage = true;

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Material(
    child: Container(
      child: Container(
        child: Row(
          children: <Widget>[
            Wrap(
              direction: Axis.vertical,
              alignment: WrapAlignment.start,
              children: <Widget>[
                IconButton(
                  icon: Icon(Icons.camera_alt),
                  iconSize: 40.0,
                  color: Color.fromRGBO(88, 60, 26, 1),
                  onPressed: () {},
                ),
                Text(
                  'Camera',
                  style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 17.0),
                )
              ],
            ),
            Spacer(), // add this
            Wrap(
              direction: Axis.vertical,
              alignment: WrapAlignment.start,
              children: <Widget>[
                IconButton(
                  icon: Icon(Icons.image),
                  iconSize: 40.0,
                  color: Color.fromRGBO(88, 60, 26, 1),
                  onPressed: () {},
                ),
                Text(
                  'Gallery',
                  style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 17.0),
                )
              ],
            ),
            Visibility( // add this
              child: Spacer(),
              visible: _hasImage,
            ),
            Visibility(
              visible: _hasImage,
              child: Wrap(
                direction: Axis.vertical,
                alignment: WrapAlignment.start,
                children: <Widget>[
                  IconButton(
                    icon: Icon(Icons.delete),
                    iconSize: 40.0,
                    color: Color.fromRGBO(88, 60, 26, 1),
                    onPressed: () {},
                  ),
                  Text(
                    'Remove',
                    style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 17.0),
                  )
                ],
              ),
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    ),
  );
}
```

Answer (score 10):

Instead of using `Visibility`, you can use `if` condition

```
Row(
  children: [
    OtherWidgets(),
    if (hasImage) YourWrapWidget(...), // only takes up space if hasImage is true
  ]
)
```

---

Full solution:

```
class _AppState extends State<App> {
  bool _hasImage;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    _hasImage = false;
    return Material(
      child: Container(
        child: Container(
          child: Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
            children: <Widget>[
              Wrap(
                direction: Axis.vertical,
                alignment: WrapAlignment.start,
                children: <Widget>[
                  IconButton(
                    icon: Icon(Icons.camera_alt),
                    iconSize: 40.0,
                    color: Color.fromRGBO(88, 60, 26, 1),
                    onPressed: () {},
                  ),
                  Text(
                    'Camera',
                    style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 17.0),
                  )
                ],
              ),
              Wrap(
                direction: Axis.vertical,
                alignment: WrapAlignment.start,
                children: <Widget>[
                  IconButton(
                    icon: Icon(Icons.image),
                    iconSize: 40.0,
                    color: Color.fromRGBO(88, 60, 26, 1),
                    onPressed: () {},
                  ),
                  Text(
                    'Gallery',
                    style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 17.0),
                  )
                ],
              ),
              if (_hasImage) // this is what you need
                Wrap(
                  direction: Axis.vertical,
                  alignment: WrapAlignment.start,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    IconButton(
                      icon: Icon(Icons.delete),
                      iconSize: 40.0,
                      color: Color.fromRGBO(88, 60, 26, 1),
                      onPressed: () {},
                    ),
                    Text(
                      'Remove',
                      style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 17.0),
                    )
                  ],
                )
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```